# Opening Powerbuilder datawindow design mode at runtime

Tags: memory, powerbuilder, datawindow, designmode

I need to use datawindow design mode in my application but i think there is no such function to open design mode at runtime.

In my application there is reporting module that is not perfect in the sense that there is always need to design a new report. I want to implement functionality in my application that will let user design reports the way he/she wants.

Designing the same interface as the one we use in design mode in powerbuilder is very difficult because there are no helping functions in powerbuilder.

The other option if possible to get syntax of a created window in design mode in powerbuilder can be seen or captured in a string from memory where powerbuilder is loaded. for example i design a datawindow in datawindow painter and do not close the painter. is there way to get the datawindow syntax from the memory where powerbuilder is loaded?

The best option would be the designer integrated in custom powerbuilder app instead of designing everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.   It's called InfoMaker, and it's fairly inexpensive.

Give your users licensed copies of IM and let them create datawindow definitions.  You can import those into your app at runtime with LibraryImport().

-Paul Horan-

Comment: Yes, that is another way to get datawindow syntax but that infomaker i think will not count as feature of my application. The best way i think is to have datawindow painter invoked from my application. I am thinking that  right click event to invoke datawindow painter will give a flexible interface to users. So they can see where in my custom application they are actually adding new report. also the same way  it will be easy for them to modify existing report.

Comment: users don't see word Powerbuilder nowhere in my application.

Comment: tight control of events handling break down if infomaker is used and new interface will be designed to cover the gap between to applications to make it easy for user to identify where in custom app they were making changes and what changes were made.

Comment: not for just reporting, anywhere in app where there is datawindow, user can right click and modify it. my app can create controls and add checks at run time without need of change in code and recompile. for example to change just position of a button or making a text bold should not load new application. That is what i think. using infomaker will help but user interface will become real ugly.

Comment: It's not possible to add the design-time datawindow painter to a run-time application.  InfoMaker is the best option here.

Answer (score 0):

In official examples "(..\Code Examples\Example App\pbexamfe.pbl)" PB there is one called "Runtime DataWindow Painter", perhaps I can help.